# Can someone give me a push in the right direction? Java XML and ResultSet

Tags: java, xml, oop, resultset

I am learning Java, and we have this task at school:

```
"XMLDecode this XML with the following class.."
```

Heres the XML-code:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9nedam40v2q8wbr/XML.xml
```

Okey, I'll try to explain simply what my problem is:
I don't know how to get these contructors to "talk". If I set the ResultSet to null, theres a NullpointerException, but I don't know how to get a resultset from this.

This is how I have started..

```
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL("THE URL TO THE XML");
        XMLDecoder ois = new XMLDecoder(url.openStream());
                    // Can also do:
                    // XMLDecoder ois = new XMLDecoder(url.openStream(), new CachingResultSetTableModel());
        ois2.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is connecting fine

As I am trying my best to ask, is how to "connect" what I have just made, into a working Table-making code.
The code is located here:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7xqkp6pb6zqyc21/CachingResultSetTableModel.java
```

Comment: This is a bit strange. On one hand, it seems what is being asked is to do some JDBC (the use of resultset). But on the other, we have XML deserialization. A total guess here would be that perhaps you are being asked to implement a the resultset interface, with the XML decoding as the back end implementation?

Comment: @javamonkey79 Yes, I found it a bit strange, but this is my first thoughts about the task. I am still not sure what to do, and how to do it.

I have a couple of weeks to solve it, and it's all about "presentation", our teacher told us. Nothing more

Comment: @OleReidarHolm There are libraries and databases that allow you to query XML. But that would be overkill for this task. So why do you think you should use ResultSet?

Comment: Hi! @RobinGreen, yep, you were right. This task was quite easy to do.. I had to read some more about XML, I did not understand it yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ResultSet has nothing to do with your problem.

The XML you posted has a fixed, not self describing grammer.  Fixed means that there is a finite set of tags that are valid.  Not self describing means that the tags have implied meanings.

1. Identify the grammar of the xml in question.  Clearly this will include "array", "object" and "void".  Probably other tags as well.
2. Identify the meaning of each tag.
3. Identify the properties of each tag.  For example, the "object" tag can have a property named "class"
4. Identify the meaning of each property.  For example, the array tag has a property named "class".  This appears to indicate the type of element stored in the array.
5. Write a SAX parser for the XML (check out this old tutorial: [SAX Parser Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html)).  Initially just print out the xml so you know it is parsing the XML correctly.  After the parser works, add the functionality for the tags and properties.
6. Unless specifically instructed to do so, don't bother reading the XML from a url.  just get the file from the dropbox then store it to a local file.

Comment: Thank you! I failed horribly, but now I have read a bit more about XML, and the SAX helped me alot.